# Questions appearing twice in quick succession

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, user-interface

At least twice today I have seen an identical question quickly appear twice in a row. Has the question-ask UI been fiddled to be a little less responsive?

(I remember the days of Netscape on Usenet. New users would post the same thing always three times and then give up. You post something, and you expect it to appear. Post it again, and that's odd it still doesn't appear. Post it a third time, and you know Netscape is really broken.)

Comment: The lack of a properly marked out screenshot... it's just so depressing.

Comment: I don't have the confidence to pull off freehand red circling.

Comment: you don't need confidence; you need photoshop.  or, y'know, MS Paint.

Answer (score 3):

OK -- looking at your specific example:

[show Jframe but not show title bar on task bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054344/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar)
tagged: [java] [sw]
Posted **2010-01-13 04:11:02Z**

[show Jframe but not show title bar on task bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054347/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar)
tagged: [java] [swing]
Posted: **2010-01-13 04:11:48Z**

So they were posted 46 seconds apart, with different tags, by the same user.

Looks like this to me:

1. user clicked "Post Your Question"
2. user realized the tag was wrong
3. user clicked back button
4. user corrected tag
5. user clicked "Post Your Question"

This requires > 10 rep since we block multiple questions for new users. This user does have 101 rep..

Correct behavior of course would have been to click "edit".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054344/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054347/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar

Comment: My guess is the user wasn't aware you can edit the tags after the fact.

Comment: @Jeff: Isn't this something trivial to "fix" with something like the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, so the user can't really "go back" after posting a question?

Comment: I don't think Post-Redirect=Get helps (unless your browser has broken its own back button). A synchro token thing might be appropriate (but in some web apps I want to go back, edit the data and really post again). I'm not a webdev, but could the page recognise it has already post and switch to edit mode? I have also noticed with dodgy Vodafone 3G/GPRS connection I loose posts when the connection drops and can't go back, but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

They don't seem to be turning up under Newest Questions, at least for meta on this question (not that I ask questions frequently).